# (+) sign in sql code

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Can anyone explain what the (+) sign means in the below code.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ph.po_nbr, rd.id
        FROM po_head a, rtable_dtl e
        WHERE a.org = e.org (+)
        AND a.menu_nbr = e.menu_nbr(+) 
        AND UPPER(a.user_id) = UPPER(e.user_id(+))
```

Comment: It's the old discouraged way of writing an outer join in Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354

Comment: This is an archaic and hard-to-understand syntax for an outer join.  I think it is a `left outer join` in this case.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff You know you're getting too old for this when you find the "archaic and hard to understand syntax" much simpler and easier to understand than the new way you kids are doing it these days.  heh.  Thats how I learned it back in the day "And we liked it!".  Now get off my lawn you darn kids.

Comment: P.S.  If you are a Toad user, it has a feature that will convert old Oracle join syntax to ANSI join syntax for you.  Select your query in the editor, then right-click and select refactor/Convert to ANSI join syntax.  You CAN teach an old dog new tricks!

Comment: @Gary_W But the notation only made sense in simple cases. So archaic or not it was inadequate. This is why `OUTER JOIN ONs` were added. Ironically since `INNER JOIN ON` was also added people think `,` is "archaic" and problematic although it is just a (loose binding) `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example:

```
SELECT 
   t0.foo, t1.bar
FROM
   FIRST_TABLE t0, SECOND_TABLE t1
WHERE
   t0.ID (+) = t1.ID;
```

This is an Oracle-specific notation for an outer join. It means that it will include all rows from t1, and use NULLS in the t0 columns if there is no corresponding row in t0.

In standard SQL one would write:

```
SELECT t0.foo, t1.bar
  FROM FIRST_TABLE t0
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN SECOND_TABLE t1;
```

Oracle [recommends not to use those joins anymore if your version supports ANSI joins (LEFT/RIGHT JOIN):](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3178)

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions […]